# Exception, Junit problem. Nothing was thrown

Tags: java, exception, junit

Why do i get a Expected prog2.NotATriangleException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown?
Below you find the code

```
public static double calcArea(double a, double b, double c) {
        checkTriangle(a, b, c);
        double s = (a + b + c)/2;
        return Math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
    }

    private static void checkTriangle(double a, double b, double c)  {
        

        try{
            checkRatio(a, b, c);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.toString();
        }


    }

   private static void checkRatio(double a, double b, double c) throws NotATriangleException {
        if (a + b <= c) {
            throw new NotATriangleException("Wont form a Triangle");
        }
```

And this this the Junit test

```
@Test
Exception b = assertThrows(NotATriangleException.class, () -> {Triangle.calcArea(5,5 ,12 );});
      assertEquals("Wont form a Triangle",b.toString());
```

Comment: I think you want `if (a + b >= c) {` instead of `if (a + b <= c) {`.

Comment: but to form a triangle a + b must be longer than c, otherwise you cannot form a triangle. I also tried it with true so that i should throw it in anycase.

Comment: You catch your Exception in the `checkTriangle` method and only call `toString` on it (for whatever reason, you aren't even printing it to the log). You aren't rethrowing the exception or anything. So when calling `checkTriangle` either directly or through `calcArea` your exception will just be swallowed.

Answer (score 0):

In the `checkTriangle`-method, you catch the exception.

```java
try{
        checkRatio(a, b, c);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.toString();
}
```

This means that while the exception occurs, the execution continuea.

`assertThrows()` just checks for exceptions that are not catched.

In order to fix this, you need not to catch and ignore the exception.

Either use an unckecked exception or add `throws NotATriangleException` to the other methods.